# android: add text to text box by pressing button

Tags: android

I am new to android developing.
Can some one please tell me how to 
Enter text into text box by pressing a button which I have created.

Eg. If I press a button label H . H must appear in text box
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Be specific how you want.

simply u can create a lay out having "a","b","c","d" etc.

then you can set on click event on that button and 
write within.

for example for on click of h button.
Write

```
textvw.setText("h");
```

Extend your question to get proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like below

..In onCreate

```
Button _mButton = (Button)findviewbyid(R.id.buttonid);
EditText edit = (EditText)findviewbyid(R.id.editextid);

_mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              edit.setText(_mButton.getText());
            }
    });
```

if You are using textview rather than edittext then replace edittedt with texview and rest will be same.